# How to use the auto-scheduler to generate schedules for GPU?

Tags: gpu, halide

I want to re-examine the experiments about the auto scheduling for GPU in the paper published at SIGGRAPH'16.

I compiled the below code using the auto-scheduler branch, but a generated code was scheduled for CPU.

How to use the auto-scheduler to generate schedules for GPU?

```
#include "Halide.h"
#include "HalideBuffer.h"
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Halide;

class conv2dHalide : public Halide::Generator<conv2dHalide>{
public:
    ImageParam in{UInt(8), 2, "input_image"};
    ImageParam kernel{Float(32), 2, "kernel"};

    Var x, y;

    Func build(){
        Func out("output_image");

    // Algorithm
       Func clamped_in;
       Expr k_wid = 3;
       Expr k_half = k_wid/2;
       Expr i_wid = in.width();
       Expr i_hei = in.height();
       Expr c_x = clamp(x, 0, in.width()-1);
       Expr c_y = clamp(y, 0, in.height()-1);

       clamped_in(x,y) = in(c_x,c_y);

       RDom r(-k_half, k_wid, -k_half, k_wid);
       r.where(k_half<=x && x<i_wid-k_half && k_half<=y && y<i_hei-k_half);
       out(x,y)=cast<uint8_t>(min(sum(clamped_in(x+r.x, y+r.y)*kernel(r.x+k_half, r.y+k_half)), 255.0f));

       out.estimate(x, 0, 512).estimate(y, 0, 512);
       in.dim(0).set_bounds_estimate(0, i_wid);
       in.dim(1).set_bounds_estimate(0, i_hei);
       kernel.dim(0).set_bounds_estimate(0, k_wid);
       kernel.dim(1).set_bounds_estimate(0, k_wid);

       Target target = Halide::get_host_target();
       target.set_feature(Target::CUDA);
       target.set_feature(Target::CUDACapability50);
       std::cout << "gpu enabled" << std::endl;

       Pipeline p(out);
       p.auto_schedule(target);
       out.print_loop_nest();

       return out;
    }

};

HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(conv2dHalide, "conv2dHalide")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (for now) cut the GPU stuff while getting the autoscheduler ready to merge into mainline Halide. I think you'd have to go back to Ravi's Halide fork he used for the siggraph paper:

https://github.com/ravi-teja-mullapudi/Halide

I'd look in the apps for examples, and open an issue on that repo if you're having trouble getting it to schedule to the GPU.